# Plotting count numbers on a New York city map + color code by neighbourhood group

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, citymaps

I have data about the Airbnb locations in New York. I also have a geojson file containing polygons to plot a map of New York. Then I made a new dataframe with pandas with the count of airbnb's per neighbourhood like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(df_listings_summary.neighbourhood.value_counts().reset_index().values, columns = ["neighbourhood", "Airbnb_per_neighbourhood"])`

`dfindex = df.sort_index(axis=0)`

Next I merged the geojson file with the dataframe that I just created:

`geoframe = pd.merge(neighbourhoods, df, on = "neighbourhood")`

So now I have a GeoDataFrame containing

1. the name of the neighbourhood
2. the name of the neighbourhood group
3. the geometry for each neighbourhood (polygon)
4. the Airbnb count per neighbourhood

Now I would like to make a city map, showing the count number on each neighbourhood. And on top of that should each number be color-coded for the corresponding neighbourhood group.
For example, there are 840 airbnb's in West Village, so on the city map on West Village must appear the number  '840'. And this number must be in Red because the corresponding neighbourhood group is Manhattan. (if the corresponding neighbourhood group would have been Bronx for example, then the number had to have another color).

Because I am a starter in Python, I haven't been able to figure this out. I tried plotting it like

`geoframe.plot(column="Airbnb_per_neighbourhood")`

based on geopandas, but that doesn't give me the desired result, only a choropleth.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What is the URL of this classroom assignment, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by the URL? But if you give me your email I can send you the files and the question through wetransfer?